# How to get XAML source from current window?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Current window is dynamically generated.

So can't get xaml source by XamlWrite.

Comment: How to get XAML source from current window? By passing file system path to writer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use `XamlWriter.Save()` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx for details).  Note that this doesn't "return the XAML source", it actually "serializes the current object in XAML form"... so you might not get quite what you expect.  On the plus side, `XamlWriter.Save()` won't care whether the window came from XAML in the first place or was dynamically generated... or even some combination of the two.